# MassTransit connection issue to rabbit mq (Messages are lost)

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have an implentation of the mass transit common publisher in our c# application it works perfectly fine most of the time with no issues . however we have noted that recently messages have been going missing when RabbitMq has gone down. if the connection has not been established or cannot be established on start then the application throws as expected and this is handled and logged to be looked at. but if the connection dissapears mid run then for some reason nothing is thrown and the message is simply lost .. is there any way to check connection status with this setup before we "publish" as the IsStarted status doesnt change if the connection drops.

heres a snipped of the code we use ( this only shows the publish part)

```
_messagePublisher.Start();
...

if (_messagePublisher.IsStarted)
            {
                
                await _messagePublisher.Publish(attempt, _messageRouter.ObtainRoutingKey(attempt));
            }
else {//Do stuff}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are losing messages, it isn't MassTransit causing it. When `Publish` is called, it will not return until the message has been delivered and acknowledged by RabbitMQ – unless you specify a `CancellationToken` and cancel it, in which case an exception will be thrown.

`IsStarted` isn't a property of any MassTransit interface, so you might look at how that property is implemented. There is a call to `CheckHealth` on the bus which could be used to verify the health status of the broker connection.